# Can i get a list of over hard and long RSA keys? i think i have found a vulnerability in RSA Algorithm

Tags: rsa

al-right, I need some examples of hard and long RSA keys cause i think i have found vulnerability in RSA.
i need you to give me few hard Values of n (which is pxq) and i will tell you what p and q are(don't tell me p and q, just tell me n)

Comment: I think this question uniquely qualifies for the "too broad" close reason: there are (literally) an [infinite number of possible answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/50006/6511).

Comment: @Reid : $\:$ :-D $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Sorry, but unless you have discovered a new branch of mathematics, it is overwhelmingly likely that you have not found a way to quickly factor large primes.

Comment: I have found a vulnerability in RSA, too. For example, I can factor $21 = 3\times 7$. I just have to deal with the last thingie: how to apply it to very, very big numbers. That's it.

Comment: If you're right and can factor the below number and RSA-2048 I'd strongly suggest you to not disclose the algorithm immediately. Maybe contact Schneier or some other well-known crypto person to make sure you don't actually harm people more than helping them. And use PGP with your mail!

Comment: i guess i need to work on on it

Comment: You can retrieve certificates from google with the openssl (and sed) commands: "openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:https < /dev/null | sed -ne '\/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,\/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p' | openssl x509 -noout -modulus"

Comment: If you can factor this, you win the Internet.  Modulus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

Comment: @user3651521 If you have openssl installed, then you can generate as many RSA keys as you like. Here's a one-liner that generates a modulus and uses [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) to convert it to decimal: `BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc<<<"ibase=16;\`openssl genrsa 2048 2>/dev/null | openssl rsa -noout -modulus |grep -o 's=.*'\`;s"` (change 2048 to the desired number of bits)

Comment: I just noticed that the "openssl x509" command does the search for the begin/end lines already, so you can skip the sed command.  I'm sorry for assuming you'd be able to convert hex to decimal, I figured that if you could break RSA you'd be able to figure that part out as well. squeamish, that's a lovely hack (changing Modulus= to s= as input to bc)!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a 2048-bit modulus $n$:

```
23345135319098428695918096856351736691605733130699443284127783899530798300904263761969678228722978488932525152955208774038661063724795894350101766091648183643636110431139209906713716077186478554224587745514191720761948637234911856612912494476420747968037052472880258891484744014484452559576872262526136662041614283437793117377679057048155066144396797991089164008590146279602387924918463421293422838064353499217789275561842179096901894289131036262707390743621266197100148615760893198749965409128055493921274609123555724795514808799093273087781413458495123664728027138459685630533762158565719480811485043587128111559163
```

in decimal. I don't mean to be negative, but if you cannot manage to find a 2048-bit RSA modulus by yourself, it's probably unlikely that you've found a vulnerability.

Comment: @user3651521: Yes. That is $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes roughly 1024 bits in size.

Comment: Factoring [RSA-2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-2048) would earn more brownie points, although the $200,000 prize is no longer on offer, unfortunately.

Comment: Had I been at my computer before the question was closed, I'd have posted RSA-2048. If you factor *that*, it shows people that you hadn't just created your own key and "factored" it, so is more helpful in showing off.

Comment: Ah, yeah, RSA-2048 would have been a better choice in retrospect. Truth be told, I just completely forgot about it.